# Change hidden input value

Tags: javascript, input, set, hidden

I want change hidden input value from other input value.

This is code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
$(\'input:text[name="'.$data['name'].'"]\').keyup(function() {
 $(\'input:hidden[id="'.$data['name'].'"]\').val( "'.$data['id'].'," + $(this).val() );
});
 });
```

This code work but i don't know how to change from keyup to always set value even if he does not edit the field and the field contains data from the database
If I don't edit the field, it won't load anything into the hidden field

I entered various functions in various ways and nothing

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `to always set value even if he does not edit the field`; why would it need to be updated if the original is not edited? What does your html look like? You should be able to initialize the value of the hidden input the same way you do the  text input.

Comment: because i must have value in input. I delete all data from database when click send and add new edited. This is only one way for my project for edit data by admin.

Comment: @mykaf I have in database same data id with other values so edit this data is impossible. Data must have same id in my project...

Comment: What about using the change event instead of keyup?

Comment: @mykaf if i set to change() work only when change input value

Comment: When else does it need to work? If the text isn't changed, why would you need to update the hidden?

Comment: must always work when page load. I must send data to one array specifications[] and have unlimited specifications. hidden value have id and value visible input must have specifications description and data.

Comment: how are you populating the original text input when the page loads?

Comment: @mykaf get data from database to input value="" and when send formulage i must delete all settings records from database and save new from input

Comment: What is preventing you from setting the hidden input value the same way when you load the page?

Comment: @mykaf becsuse i join other data in one hidden input: value="data1,data_from_input,data3" and data1 and data3 is not editable if I delete all records and add new i must have saved data

Comment: So what I'm understanding is that upon page load you set the text input's value to its own value, but then set the hidden input's value to multiple values. Then when you change the text input, you want to update the hidden input to the same value. If so, your "other data" would be overwritten, correct? Perhaps you need more hidden inputs to handle the other hidden data.

Comment: @mykaf all works when I edit input. if input no edit this not worki. I don't know how to change code for working when input no edit.

Comment: You haven't included any html in the question, so it's really hard to tell what exactly is going on. If you need the correct value if the text input isn't edited, then you need to start with the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

try to use
following code , it changes the value of input:text when input:hidden value changes.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        // this part handles when input:text field changes value 
            $('input:text[name="' + $data['name'] + '"]').on('input', function() {
                $('input:hidden[id="' + $data['name'] + '"]').val($data['id'] + ',' + $(this).val());
              });

// this part handles when loading page , set value of hidden input by value of input:text value 
    let $textInput = $('input:text[name="' + $data['name'] + '"]');
        let $hiddenInput = $('input:hidden[id="' + $data['name'] + '"]');
   let $textval = $textInput.val();
      $hiddenInput.val($textval);
            });
```

Comment: Work only when i set input value

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).